# How to sort / merge two maps in terraform

Tags: sorting, merge, maps, terraform

Can someone help me figure this out?  I'm using terraform 12.28.

I have two maps that look like this:

```
instances = { 
  "instance1" = "us-east-1a"
  "instance2" = "us-east-1a"
  "instance3" = "us-east-1c"
  "instance4" = "us-east-1b"
  "instance5" = "us-east-1b"
  "instance6" = "us-east-1c"
}

snapshots = {
  "snap1" = "us-east-1c"
  "snap2" = "us-east-1b"
  "snap3" = "us-east-1b"
  "snap4" = "us-east-1c"
  "snap5" = "us-east-1a"
  "snap6" = "us-east-1a"
}
```

What I would like to get  out of this is:

```
desired_result = {
  "instance1" = "snap5"
  "instance2" = "snap6"
  "instnace3" = "snap1"
  "instance4" = "snap2"
  "instance5" = "snap3" 
  "instance6" = "snap4"
}
```

I just need to ensure that the instance has a snap from that same az. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How is it supposed to work? `instance6` has az of `useast-1c`. There is no such az in `snapshots` due to spelling mistakes. The spelling mistakes are actual  part of your task?

Comment: Also `instance2` has az of `us-east-1a`. There are two snapshots with such az? Both of them should be accounted, or only the first one, the last one?

Comment: My bad, that was a typo.  All the az's should match on both maps.  I have corrected the example.

Answer (score 1):

The outcome you described is not possible, since your lookup values overlap. `Instance1` and `instance2` could both lead to `snap5` or `snap6`, since they are both located in `us-east-1a`. The same holds true for the other availability zones. One way to get the actual result is by reversing one of the lists and grouping the values. After this, you can use that that list to lookup the corresponding value in the other list. Here is my example:

```
locals {
  instances = {
    "instance1" = "us-east-1a"
    "instance2" = "us-east-1a"
    "instance3" = "us-east-1c"
    "instance4" = "us-east-1b"
    "instance5" = "us-east-1b"
    "instance6" = "us-east-1c"
  }
  snapshots = {
    "snap1" = "us-east-1c"
    "snap2" = "us-east-1b"
    "snap3" = "us-east-1b"
    "snap4" = "us-east-1c"
    "snap5" = "us-east-1a"
    "snap6" = "us-east-1a"
  }
  # Reverse and group (...)
  reversed_snapshots = {
    for key, value in local.snapshots:
    value => key...
  }
}

output "result" {
  value = {
    for key, value in local.instances:
    # Match instance to snapshots by looking up az
    key => lookup(local.reversed_snapshots, value, null)
  }
}
```

The outcome is somewhat different than the outcome in the original question, since every instance could basically have one of the two snapshots that are located in the same AZ. The common identifier AZ has duplicate values, so maybe you can find another identifier that is unique, like snapshotID or something similar. Or maybe it is just not a problem that **two** snapshots could be related to **one** instance.

```
result = {
  "instance1" = [
    "snap5",
    "snap6",
  ]
  "instance2" = [
    "snap5",
    "snap6",
  ]
  "instance3" = [
    "snap1",
    "snap4",
  ]
  "instance4" = [
    "snap2",
    "snap3",
  ]
  "instance5" = [
    "snap2",
    "snap3",
  ]
  "instance6" = [
    "snap1",
    "snap4",
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you can probably tell, I was trying to map volumes to instances in the same availability_zone for a disaster recovery terraform script.  The original (pre-disaster) cluster had an equal number of instances distributed between 3 availability zones.  In the case of a disaster, I need to restore the cluster across the same number of availability zones, preserving the node to availability zone group combinations.

I'm not sure if this is the cleanest way to solve this, but here is what I ended up doing.  If anyone has a better/cleaner way of doing this, I am still open to suggestions, but I'm happy to at least have this working now.

First, I ended up creating an tuple of maps of maps of strings, based on the availability zones like this:

```
instance_az = [
  flatten([for instance in aws_instance.cassandra: 
    map(
      instance.availability_zone,
      zipmap(
        matchkeys(
          tolist(aws_instance.cassandra.*.id),
          tolist(aws_instance.cassandra.*.availability_zone),  
          [instance.availability_zone]
        ),
        matchkeys(
          tolist(aws_ebs_volume.data.*.id),
          tolist(aws_ebs_volume.data.*.availability_zone),        
          [instance.availability_zone]
        )
      )
    )
  ])
]
```

Example output:

```
instance_az = [
  [
    {
      "us-east-1c" = {
        "i-0a18b339d3f1ddd80" = "vol-0ace4794f40c256ed"
        "i-0bd9681b1b856c3db" = "vol-00f694635ef7b0904"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1a" = {
        "i-033c004ed25dbd907" = "vol-0a31e52f2e11dfdef"
        "i-0ed01a562756800e9" = "vol-0a20cabb0ae568084"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1b" = {
        "i-0400baef538ea327a" = "vol-060aff04e902f7005"
        "i-08ed6b26743a2bd95" = "vol-06917d88b07bd5d5c"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1c" = {
        "i-0a18b339d3f1ddd80" = "vol-0ace4794f40c256ed"
        "i-0bd9681b1b856c3db" = "vol-00f694635ef7b0904"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1a" = {
        "i-033c004ed25dbd907" = "vol-0a31e52f2e11dfdef"
        "i-0ed01a562756800e9" = "vol-0a20cabb0ae568084"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1b" = {
        "i-0400baef538ea327a" = "vol-060aff04e902f7005"
        "i-08ed6b26743a2bd95" = "vol-06917d88b07bd5d5c"
      }
    },
  ],
]
```

The problem with that output is that each availability zone was listed twice with the exact same instanceId->volumeId map.  Next, I wanted to remove the duplicates, so I converted it to a set like this:

```
  inst_vol_to_set = {
    s = toset(local.instance_az[0])
  }
```

Now my output looks like this:

```
inst_vol_to_set = {
  "s" = [
    {
      "us-east-1a" = {
        "i-033c004ed25dbd907" = "vol-0a31e52f2e11dfdef"
        "i-0ed01a562756800e9" = "vol-0a20cabb0ae568084"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1b" = {
        "i-0400baef538ea327a" = "vol-060aff04e902f7005"
        "i-08ed6b26743a2bd95" = "vol-06917d88b07bd5d5c"
      }
    },
    {
      "us-east-1c" = {
        "i-0a18b339d3f1ddd80" = "vol-0ace4794f40c256ed"
        "i-0bd9681b1b856c3db" = "vol-00f694635ef7b0904"
      }
    },
  ]
}
```

Ok that is looking more like what I wanted to accomplish.  Now, I just need to convert that to a map of instanceId->VolumeId:

```
  inst_vol = [
    flatten([for s in lookup(local.inst_vol_to_set, "s"): [
      for key in keys(s): [
        for idx, v in keys(s[key]): {
          "${v}" = lookup(s[key], v)
        }

      ]
    ]])
  ]
```

Now this is looking better, but it's still a tuple of maps:

```
inst_vol = [
  [
    {
      "i-033c004ed25dbd907" = "vol-0a31e52f2e11dfdef"
    },
    {
      "i-0ed01a562756800e9" = "vol-0a20cabb0ae568084"
    },
    {
      "i-0400baef538ea327a" = "vol-060aff04e902f7005"
    },
    {
      "i-08ed6b26743a2bd95" = "vol-06917d88b07bd5d5c"
    },
    {
      "i-0a18b339d3f1ddd80" = "vol-0ace4794f40c256ed"
    },
    {
      "i-0bd9681b1b856c3db" = "vol-00f694635ef7b0904"
    },
  ],
]
```

The last thing to do is to flatten the result so that I can lookup the instance_id and have it return the volume_id:

```
instance_to_volume_map = merge(flatten(local.inst_vol)...)
```

Now this is exactly what I wanted:

```
instance_to_volume_map = {
  "i-033c004ed25dbd907" = "vol-0a31e52f2e11dfdef"
  "i-0400baef538ea327a" = "vol-060aff04e902f7005"
  "i-08ed6b26743a2bd95" = "vol-06917d88b07bd5d5c"
  "i-0a18b339d3f1ddd80" = "vol-0ace4794f40c256ed"
  "i-0bd9681b1b856c3db" = "vol-00f694635ef7b0904"
  "i-0ed01a562756800e9" = "vol-0a20cabb0ae568084"
}
```